# What are all the positive integers, $n$, that $2^n-1$ is divisible by $7$? What are all the positive integers for $n$ that $2^n+1$ is divisible by $7$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have been working on these problems, and I haven't been able to get an answer.

So far, I have tried working out the problems $\mod 4$ since $2^n - 1$ will always be $3 \mod 4$, and $2^n + 1$ will always be $1 \mod 4$, but I found out that the multiples of $7 (\mod 4)$ follow a pattern, and there would be infinitely many.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find the integers $n$ so that $2^n\equiv 1 \bmod 7$. Looking at the residues when dividing $2^n$ by $7$ we get:

$2,4,1,2,4,1\dots$

So you want the values  such that $3|n$

Comment: What do you mean by residues?

Comment: if you divide $2$ by $7$ the residue is $2$. If you divide $4$ by $7$ the residue is $4$. If you divide $8$ by $7$ the residue is $1$ and so on...

Comment: Positive remainders